# Ruby on Rails - Model Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im working on a little app for Ruby on Rails and Ive got a question regarding the relationship between models.

I have "Teams" which play against each other in "Matches"

The tables currently look like this although I might have to make some changes to the matches table.

Teams:

```
 id   | Name
 1    | some-name#1
 2    | some-name#2   
 3    | some-name#3
```

Matches

```
id   | team_id1 | team_id2 | result1 | result2
 1   |     2    |    3     |    -1   |   -1
```

In this example the team with id 2 plays against team with id 3. The result is not yet entered and therefore set to "-1" for both. If Team 2 would loose against Team 3 with a score of "3:7" then result1 would be "3" and result2 "7"

A Team has many matches and one match belongs to two teams.

How can i model the relationships in Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

team.rb

```
has_many :matches
```

matches.rb

```
belongs_to :team_one, :foreign_key => "team_id1", :class_name => "Team"
belongs_to :team_two, :foreign_key => "team_id2", :class_name => "Team"
```

In this case suppose you want to find team one's name and team two's name from the object of matches do following

```
match = match.find(1)
match.team_one.name ### gives -> some-name#2
match.team_two.name ### gives -> some-name#3
```

Comment: Would it be another solution to assign class_name to the models and use an habtm relation?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Ive been playing around with it in the console and one thing i noticed is that i can save a match even though there are no corresponding teams to the team_id 1/2 that i assigned to the match.

For Example: i can save a match with team_id1 set to "5" even though there is no Team with id 5

Is that intentional?